# Postgres code to calculate customer revenue retention by month

Tags: sql, project, pgadmin

Working on a personal project to calculate customer retention month over month (jan through december) for one year. Essentially how many customers are retained (%) since the first month, grouped by the first month that the customer joined to explore user behavior (those that joined in january at the january cohort etc).

Im a true beginner and trying to learn so any help would be appreciated! apologies if any of this is rudimentary
Tech Stack + versions: PGAdmin 4, version 6.19 (desktop, windows 10 operating system)
Current outcome: getting an error code specifically around the grouping. I am not sure how to fix it.
Expected outcome: screenshot of desired / expected outcome (cohort percentages)
[image: screenshot here]
Thank you in advance for your help!

```
CREATE TABLE customer_revenue (
    customer_name varchar (100),
    revenue_jan DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_feb DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_mar DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_april DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_may DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_june DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_july DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_aug DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_sept DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_oct DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_nov DECIMAL(10,0),
    revenue_dec DECIMAL(10,0));
    


COPY customer_revenue (customer_name, revenue_jan, revenue_feb, revenue_mar, revenue_april, revenue_may, revenue_june, revenue_july, revenue_aug, revenue_sept, revenue_oct, revenue_nov, revenue_Dec)
-- replaced my directory name with placeholder
FROM [MY DIRECTPRY] 
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);




WITH cohort_items AS (
  SELECT
    customer_name,
    CASE
      WHEN revenue_jan > 0 THEN 'January'
      WHEN revenue_feb > 0 THEN 'February'
      WHEN revenue_mar > 0 THEN 'March'
      WHEN revenue_april > 0 THEN 'April'
      WHEN revenue_may > 0 THEN 'May'
      WHEN revenue_june > 0 THEN 'June'
      WHEN revenue_july > 0 THEN 'July'
      WHEN revenue_aug > 0 THEN 'August'
      WHEN revenue_sept > 0 THEN 'September'
      WHEN revenue_oct > 0 THEN 'October'
      WHEN revenue_nov > 0 THEN 'November'
      WHEN revenue_dec > 0 THEN 'December'
    END AS cohort_month
  FROM customer_revenue
),
cohort_size AS (
  SELECT cohort_month, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_name) AS num_customers
  FROM cohort_items
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY MIN(CASE cohort_month
                  WHEN 'January' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'February' THEN 2
                  WHEN 'March' THEN 3
                  WHEN 'April' THEN 4
                  WHEN 'May' THEN 5
                  WHEN 'June' THEN 6
                  WHEN 'July' THEN 7
                  WHEN 'August' THEN 8
                  WHEN 'September' THEN 9
                  WHEN 'October' THEN 10
                  WHEN 'November' THEN 11
                  WHEN 'December' THEN 12
              END)
),
B AS (
  SELECT
    C.cohort_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT C.customer_name) AS num_customers
  FROM cohort_items C
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cohort_items
    WHERE cohort_month = C.cohort_month
      AND customer_name = C.customer_name  )
  GROUP BY C.cohort_month
)
SELECT
  B.cohort_month,
  S.num_customers AS total_customers,
  (B.num_customers::float / S.num_customers::float) * 100 AS percentage
FROM B
LEFT JOIN cohort_size S ON B.cohort_month = S.cohort_month
WHERE B.cohort_month IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.cohort_month
ORDER BY MIN(CASE B.cohort_month
                WHEN 'January' THEN 1
                WHEN 'February' THEN 2
                WHEN 'March' THEN 3
                WHEN 'April' THEN 4
                WHEN 'May' THEN 5
                WHEN 'June' THEN 6
                WHEN 'July' THEN 7
                WHEN 'August' THEN 8
                WHEN 'September' THEN 9
                WHEN 'October' THEN 10
                WHEN 'November' THEN 11
                WHEN 'December' THEN 12
            END);
```

SNIPPET OF WHAT MY DATA LOOKS LIKE (formatted this in github markdown format per the instructions)

| Customer ID | Revenue Jan | Revenue Feb | Revenue March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | 3300 | 3300 | 3300 |
| Customer 2 | 9900 | 9900 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | 0 | 8250 | 8250 |

Comment: What would really help your cause is "sample data" (ideally table definition(s) and inserts, or simple text that can be parsed, or setup a "fiddle" e.g. https://db-fiddle.uk) and you should avoid reliance on images wherever possible. Then also provide the "expected result" - this should be derivable from the sample your data you provide. Also, if referencing an error message - copy/paste the entire message into your question.

Comment: Your problem is in the final `SELECT` where you have an `ORDER BY MIN()`.  Because you are using an aggregate in the order by, all the items in the `SELECT` must either be included in the `GROUP BY` or must themselves be aggregated.  What is your `ORDER BY MIN` supposed to be doing?  Without sample data, we cannot test it, but it looks to me wrong,  `ORDER BY` followed by an integer refers to the column to be used for the ordering.  You will potentially order by a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock hi Jonathan, thanks for your reply. recognize the error is in the Order by but not sure how to fix it. my data is originally in excel and has one column for customer name and 12 columns for revenue (january through december). trying to group by those months. thanks!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I added a snip of the code. thanks!

Comment: @PaulMaxwell hi Paul, thank you for replying. ive added sample code. thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you re-consider how to approach your problem. You probably need to move the data into a different structure to assist your queries (this is called an "unpivot" as your data is currently a "pivot").

nb: This is "sample data":

```
INSERT INTO customer_revenue (customer_name, revenue_jan, revenue_feb, revenue_mar, revenue_april, revenue_may, revenue_june, revenue_july, revenue_aug, revenue_sept, revenue_oct, revenue_nov, revenue_dec)
VALUES
  ('Customer A', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200),
  ('Customer B', null, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300),
  ('Customer C', null, null, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400),
  ('Customer D', null, null, null, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500),
  ('Customer E', null, null, null, null, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600),
  ('Customer F', null, null, null, null, null, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700),
  ('Customer G', null, null, null, null, null, null, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800),
  ('Customer H', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900),
  ('Customer I', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000),
  ('Customer J', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1900, 2000, 2100)
  ;
```

From that sample data you can see 10 customers, each starting in a different month. This query should help determine the number of retained customers per month.

```
WITH revenue_by_month AS (
      /* "unpivot" the source data into a "normalized" structure */
      SELECT customer_name, 1 AS month, revenue_jan AS revenue   FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 2, revenue_feb FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 3, revenue_mar FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 4, revenue_april FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 5, revenue_may FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 6, revenue_june FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 7, revenue_july FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 8, revenue_aug FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 9, revenue_sept FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 10, revenue_oct FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 11, revenue_nov FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 12, revenue_dec FROM customer_revenue
      )
  , first_month_by_customer AS (
      /* calculate "first month" per customer */
      SELECT
            customer_name
          , MIN(case when revenue IS NOT NULL then month end) AS first_month
      FROM revenue_by_month
      GROUP BY customer_name
      )
SELECT
      month
    , COUNT(case when revenue IS NOT NULL then first_month_by_customer.customer_name end) AS retention
FROM revenue_by_month 
LEFT JOIN first_month_by_customer
  ON first_month_by_customer.customer_name = revenue_by_month.customer_name
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
;
```

| month | retention |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 |
| 10 | 10 |
| 11 | 10 |
| 12 | 10 |

Try it interactively at this ["fiddle"](https://dbfiddle.uk/tOCnqvUU)

Comment: thank you! I did a pivot because i would like to left pivot to create the % retention that I have in the picture (i created that with formulas in excel). I am trying to calculate the % retained vs. count but unsure how to do

Comment: If you are going to use SQL you do NOT want the data in a pivot - it will make your job far harder. Do as many calculations as you can first, THEN pivot for presentation. nb: If you only want an Excel solution don't use tags that will invite SQL answers.

Comment: For percentages explain in words how each percentage is calculated. e.g. Do you use the count @first_month each time? i.e. current_count / first_month count ? Oh! by the way - I cannot see any images in the question - that's why it is recommended you avoid them.

Comment: Hi Paul Im looking for a solution in SQL. Simply saying that I do this workflow manually in Excel but its time consuming and not scalable...so yes Im trying to learn to do in SQL....i see the image on my end so strange

Comment: The reason I need to left pivot is for the percentages. The formula is (dollar of customer revenue today) / (dollars of customer revenue month 1 for this cohort) *100. for instance for customers who joined march that is the march cohort, say $100k in total revenue in march from all new customers that month. lets day by may there's only $70k remaining (some customers left etc.) so i take (70/ 100)*100 and that is 70% revenue retention from march to april

Comment: You will eventually learn that data in a pivoted format is NOT "SQL friendly" it makes SQL queries MUCH more complex. *FYI - I cannot see images at any Stack site due to network policy, the site that hosts the image is blocked.*

Comment: How should I share the image so that you are able to see?

Answer (score 0):

The following logic should match the first month revenue to subsequent months allowing for the desired percentage calculation.

```
INSERT INTO customer_revenue (customer_name, revenue_jan, revenue_feb, revenue_mar, revenue_april, revenue_may, revenue_june, revenue_july, revenue_aug, revenue_sept, revenue_oct, revenue_nov, revenue_dec)
VALUES
  ('Customer A', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,  null, null, null),
  ('Customer B', null, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,  null, null, null),
  ('Customer C', null, null, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, null, null, null),
  ('Customer D', null, null, null, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500),
  ('Customer E', null, null, null, null, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600),
  ('Customer F', null, null, null, null, null, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700),
  ('Customer G', null, null, null, null, null, null, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800),
  ('Customer H', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900),
  ('Customer I', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000),
  ('Customer J', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1900, 2000, 2100)
  ;

WITH revenue_by_month AS (
      /* "unpivot" the source data into a "normalized" structure */
      SELECT customer_name, 1 AS month, revenue_jan AS revenue   FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 2, revenue_feb FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 3, revenue_mar FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 4, revenue_april FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 5, revenue_may FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 6, revenue_june FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 7, revenue_july FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 8, revenue_aug FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 9, revenue_sept FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 10, revenue_oct FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 11, revenue_nov FROM customer_revenue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT customer_name, 12, revenue_dec FROM customer_revenue
      )
  , first_month_by_customer AS (
        /* calculate first month revenue */
        SELECT
              f.customer_name
            , f.first_month
            , sum(m.revenue) * 1.0 AS first_revenue
        FROM (
            /* calculate "first month" per customer */
            SELECT
                  customer_name
                , MIN(CASE WHEN revenue IS NOT NULL THEN month END) AS first_month
            FROM revenue_by_month
            GROUP BY customer_name
            ) AS f
        INNER JOIN revenue_by_month AS m ON f.customer_name = m.customer_name
                                        AND f.first_month = m.month
        GROUP BY
              f.customer_name
            , f.first_month
      )
SELECT
      m.month
    , SUM(m.retention) AS retained
    , SUM(m.first_revenue) AS first_revenue
    , SUM(m.revenue) AS revenue
    , SUM(m.revenue) / SUM(m.first_revenue) AS retention_pct
FROM (
    SELECT
          m.month
        , m.customer_name
        , COUNT(case when m.revenue IS NOT NULL then f.customer_name end) AS retention
        , SUM(m.revenue) AS revenue
        , SUM(case when m.month >= f.first_month then f.first_revenue end) as first_revenue
    FROM revenue_by_month AS m
    INNER JOIN first_month_by_customer AS f ON f.customer_name = m.customer_name
    GROUP BY
          m.month
        , m.customer_name
    ) AS m
GROUP BY
     m.month
ORDER BY
     month
```

| month | retained | first_revenue | revenue | retention_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100.0 | 100 | 1.00000000000000000000 |
| 2 | 2 | 400.0 | 500 | 1.2500000000000000 |
| 3 | 3 | 900.0 | 1200 | 1.3333333333333333 |
| 4 | 4 | 1600.0 | 2200 | 1.3750000000000000 |
| 5 | 5 | 2500.0 | 3500 | 1.4000000000000000 |
| 6 | 6 | 3600.0 | 5100 | 1.4166666666666667 |
| 7 | 7 | 4900.0 | 7000 | 1.4285714285714286 |
| 8 | 8 | 6400.0 | 9200 | 1.4375000000000000 |
| 9 | 9 | 8100.0 | 11700 | 1.4444444444444444 |
| 10 | 7 | 10000.0 | 11200 | 1.12000000000000000000 |
| 11 | 7 | 10000.0 | 11900 | 1.19000000000000000000 |
| 12 | 7 | 10000.0 | 12600 | 1.26000000000000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bNXh4LEJ)

**NB** I am not attempting to "pivot" the final result as there are thousands of examples of how to do this (and you have not specified which database you are actually using, which you should always do in future questions).

Comment: Thanks, im still trying to solve for something different. again, not sure how i can share that picture. its not hosted anywhere on my end it shows up as part of the question (based on the guidelines)

Comment: Forget about the picture - I have seen it using my phone - it does NOT help explain the required logic, AND as I keep saying, in SQL, only pivot at the last moment for presentation. In fact generally speaking that type of report presentation isn't done in SQL at all. I'm not devoting further time to this question. If my efforts haven't helped I suggest you open a new question with "sample data" and "expected result" and avoid pictures (even the image you want to use can be represented as text) nb: the expected result should be derived only from the sample data